# How can I identify the leader of a process group in linux?

Tags: process

I understand that when a process is started from a shell in linux or unix, a new process group is created with that process as the process leader, giving its PID equal to a new PGID which is used for any processes spawn from that process.

As I understand it, in the case where the process leader is terminated, a new process becomes leader. This new leader would then have a PID inequal to the PGID of the process group. So then, looking at all the processes in the group, how would I identify which is the leader?

Comment: Did you try `ps fax`?

Comment: I tried `ps axjf` which is I think roughly equivalent. The problem isn't getting the PID and PGID fields, its interpreting them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run:

```
pgrep -g <PGID>
```

This will return you all the PIDs of the group.
The first one is the leader.

You could run if you only want the leader:

```
pgrep -g <PGID> | head -1
```